# How to size a XIB cell so that 2 labels can appear?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm smashing my head against the wall for the past 3 hours trying to figure this out. After watching countless tutorials, I still can't seem to figure out why this XIB cell cannot show both labels on the tableview.

XIB file:
[image]

What it keeps showing up as:

[image]

I just don't understand. I've tried everything, setting height constraints, distance constraints, stack views, but nothing will get the second label on the bottom to show up in the table view cell. Is there an obvious thing I am missing here?

Comment: I keep getting this error: Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a table view cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead. Cell

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is absolutely insipid but I figured it out, by randomly copying and pasting bits of code online until something worked. Here's what worked (swiped from [hackingwithswift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/ios/uitableview-automatic-row-height-programatically/2203))

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor,constant: 5),
        titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor),
        titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor),
        titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: projLabel.topAnchor),
        
        
        projLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor),
        projLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor),
        projLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor),
        projLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
    ])
```

final result: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Select TableView in Storyboard -> Identity Inspector

- Set Row Height to Automatic (let empty)
- Set estimate to some value (for example 150)

On cell class implement this method (example):

```
override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    // 1) Set the contentView's width to the specified size parameter
    contentView.pin.width(size.width)

    // 2) Layout the contentView's controls
    layout()

    // 3) Returns a size that contains all controls
    return CGSize(width: contentView.frame.width, height: adsViewsCount.frame.maxY + padding)
}
```

Implement this with UITableViewDatasource:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    // The UITableView will call the cell's sizeThatFit() method to compute the height.
    // WANRING: You must also set the UITableView.estimatedRowHeight for this to work.
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

Comment: Hey - I'm getting the following errors. I don't know if there's something I'm doing wrong but it's not immediately obvious how to implement this into my code...

Comment: Value of type UIView has no member pin

Comment: cannot find layout in scope

Comment: cannot find adsViewCount in scope

Comment: @LionelYu that is a simple example. I use a library called PinLayout for layout. I don't use apple Auto Layout at all. And the layout function is a function created by me using PinLayout. Here the project on GitHub: https://github.com/layoutBox/PinLayout